# Using IAM roles to generate a dynamic inventory for Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-iam, boto

I'm looking at setting up a deploy server within our VPC and am trying to use an IAM role instead of keys for Ansibles dynamic [`ec2.py`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py) inventory script.

An answer at [Can I use IAM Roles for Ansible](https://serverfault.com/questions/691971/can-i-use-iam-roles-for-ansible) says it is possible, however it does *not* indicate what permission are required.

I'm wondering if someone is able to provide some more details on what permissions are needed to be able to generate a dynamic inventory.

Edit: I've reviewed the docs and I think part of the solution is figuring out what permissions botos [get_all_instances()](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.get_all_instances) needs.

Comment: when you run it, how does it fail?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the only inventory you want are EC2 based resources, then allowing the "ec2:Describe*" actions should be sufficient:

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": "ec2:Describe*",
"Resource": "*"
```

See [Allow users to list the Amazon EC2 resources that belong to the AWS account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExamplePolicies_EC2.html#ex1)

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to the AWS management console. Go to `Identity & Access Management/Roles/Create New Role`
2. Give your role a name, for example `ansible` because the instance with this role will run Ansible.
3. Under `AWS Service Roles` select `Amazon EC2`
4. Select `Power User Access` you will have a policy name and a policy document, one JSON string like this:

```
   {
        "Version": "20XX-XX-XX",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "NotAction": "iam:*",
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

5. `Next Step/Create Role`
6. You will have an instance profile with the same name that you give to your role, and the role will be associated to the instance profile. Now, when you create the new instance for Ansible deploy, you will give this instance profile to the instance, and this instance will have the permissions for the role.